# Is it possible to serialize derived properties of list members in System.Text.Json?

Tags: c#, serialization, .net-core, .net-core-3.0, system.text.json

According to the [documentation of `System.Text.Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#serialize-properties-of-derived-classes):

> To serialize the properties of the derived type, use one of the following approaches:
>
> - (...)
> - Declare the object to be serialized as `object`.

Unfortunately, as I've just found out, this does not allow to serialize derived properties of list members. Consider the following DTO classes:

```cs
public abstract class GameUpdate
{
    public abstract string Type { get; }
}

public class ConsoleMessage : GameUpdate
{
    public override string Type => "ConsoleMessage";

    public string MessageContent { get; set; }
}

public class HitpointsUpdate : GameUpdate
{
    public override string Type => "HitpointsUpdate";

    public long MonsterID { get; set; }
    public long NewHP { get; set; }
}
```

They are supposed to be used as a `List<GameUpdate>`. Unfortunately, declaring the list to be serialized as `object` still fails to serialize important properties:

```cs
var gameUpdates = new List<GameUpdate>
{
    new ConsoleMessage { MessageContent = "Chimzee lost 10 HP!"},
    new HitpointsUpdate { MonsterID = 5, NewHP = 90 }
};
var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize<object>(gameUpdates);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

This produces the following JSON:

```js
[{"Type":"ConsoleMessage"},{"Type":"HitpointsUpdate"}]
```

For comparison, using `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(gameUpdates)` produces the following result:

```js
[{"Type":"ConsoleMessage","MessageContent":"Chimzee lost 10 HP!"},{"Type":"HitpointsUpdate","MonsterID":5,"NewHP":90}]
```

Is it possible to achieve similar results using `System.Text.Json`?

<sub>Why I'm asking this: I'm perpetually trying to develop a browser-based game as a hobby project and this is precisely how I implemented how the server communicates with the browser. As Asp .NET Core 3 came out [its documentation encourages to migrate from Newtonsoft.JSON to System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#jsonnet-support). Having read in the documentation that polymorphic serialization was possible I removed Newtonsoft-related code and started using System.Text.Json, only to find out that the game is no longer working.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this works:

```
var gameUpdates = new List<object>
{
    new ConsoleMessage { MessageContent = "Chimzee lost 10 HP!"},
    new HitpointsUpdate { MonsterID = 5, NewHP = 90 }
};

var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(gameUpdates);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

`[{"Type":"ConsoleMessage","MessageContent":"Chimzee lost 10 HP!"},{"Type":"HitpointsUpdate","MonsterID":5,"NewHP":90}]`

A side-note: Your approach might be dangerous, you have to keep a whitelist of allowed types to Deserialize again or an attacker could inject the creation of his own types...It's much safer to just serialize one type of object in one collection.

What if an attacker injects code like this:

> "Type":"System.Drawing.Bitmap","Width":"100000", "Height":"100000"

Comment: On the side of C#, I validate that whatever type is expected is assignable from the type provided by the JSON - so in this example I believe that `System.Drawing.Bitmap` would fail this validation since  `GameUpdate` is not assignable from `System.Drawing.Bitmap`. On the side of JS this doesn't matter fortunately, sometime dynamic typing seems really convenient. Perhaps using a single type would be better as you suggest, but I can't see how to do this, since different situations require different updates *with different sets of information*.

Comment: Another problem is that if `ConsoleMessageUpdate` contains properties that follow the same pattern - ie there is an abstract class `ConsoleMessagePart` and derived classes `ConsoleMessageMonsterPart`, `ConsoleMessageTextPart`, ..., and `ConsoleMessageUpdate` contains the property `List<ConsoleMessagePart> Parts {get; set;}` (which is the case...) - I have to switch the type of this list to `List<object>`... Eh this is becoming misleading already, I think I'm switching back to JSON.NET.

Comment: When the serializer is forcing me to change the code and make it worse (use object) then that library has failed.